# RSPEC Calling Methods Error

Tags: ruby, methods, rspec, tdd, call

Here's the method that's giving the error/falure:

```
def draw?(board)
    if full?(board) == true && won?(board) == false
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

The method does everything is supposed to do **but** this is the error that appears when I run the rspec file:

```
1) ./lib/tic_tac_toe.rb #draw? calls won? and full?                                                                                    
     Failure/Error: expect(self).to receive(:won?).with(board)                                                                           
       (#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::LibTicTacToeRb::Draw:0x00000002e300b0>).won?(["X", "O", "X", "O", "X", "X", "O", "X", "O"])              
           expected: 1 time with arguments: (["X", "O", "X", "O", "X", "X", "O", "X", "O"])                                              
           received: 0 times
```

Here's the rspec test:

```
describe '#draw?' do

    it 'calls won? and full?' do
      board = ["X", "O", "X", "O", "X", "X", "O", "X", "O"]
      expect(self).to receive(:won?).with(board)
      expect(self).to receive(:full?).with(board)

      draw?(board)
    end
```

Essentially, I read: **#draw? fails to call #full? and #won?**

But when I look at my #draw? method, **I do call them!** as the "if" conditional!

So **where am I going wrong**?

Help is greatly appreciated!

I'm currently learning Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your entire `draw?` method can be simplified to one line: `full?(board) && !won?(board)`

2) Your need your `expect` to be spying on an instance of the class, or the class itself if you're testing class methods. You're using `self` which will be RSpec itself, *not* the underlying class you're testing. Since I don't know the name of it, I'll assume it's called `Game`. Try something like this:

```
describe '#draw?' do
  it 'calls draw? and full?' do
    board = ["X", "O", "X", "O", "X", "X", "O", "X", "O"]
    game = Game.new
    expect(game).to receive(:won?).with(board)
    expect(game).to receive(:full?).with(board)
    game.draw?
  end
end
```

3) Another issue here is that you're expecting both methods to be called, but `won?` won't be called if `full?` returns `false`. This is due to [**short circuiting**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). In situations where all statements must evaluate to true (or false), once one of them does not, the rest are not evaluated. Think of an example like: `if user != nil && user.admin?`. You *want* short-circuiting here so that the second statement does not get evaluated if the first isn't true. And in general it's an unnecessary use of resources to evaluate statements whose output doesn't matter.

4) Lastly, in general you're best off testing the output of the function rather than the internals of how it works. Better off having a bunch of tests where you pass in data and then `expect` a result.

Comment: I forgot about short circuiting, thanks! This was part of a online lesson I'm going through and I'm not supposed to touch the tests, but testing the output of the function does make more sense! Rspec still threw errors for the overall CLI I made for a tic-tac-toe game even though it worked great. So I moved on. Really appreciate the info!